# Deployed Shiny app on Shiny Server won't show up when embedded in iframe

Tags: r, shiny, server, shiny-server

I have built a couple of Shiny apps on a Shiny Server by following [this article](https://www.marinedatascience.co/blog/2019/04/28/run-shiny-server-on-your-own-digitalocean-droplet-part-2/index.html#configuration). When I go to the specific app's webpage from my server, it is showing up just fine (see below).

[image]

However, when I embed it onto my website using iframe, though, I just get a blank page (see below).

[image]

When I go to hit "Publish" on the Shiny App from my RStudio Server site, I don't have a login, but I didn't think I needed one when it's hosted on a Shiny Server.

[image]

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to provide more information without giving away my IP, but any help would be appreciated!